# Difference between TRAP and exceptions

Tags: exception, operating-system, os-trap

Taking an Operating System course.
So I've understood both TRAPs and exceptions can be considered software interrupts... so they are both internal and synchronous.
However I can't seem to figure out the difference between the two definitions.
So if anybody wouldn't mind explaining and giving some examples it'd be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Both are very close. Exception is the hardware concept (for instance div-by-0 raises an exception in the processor). While traps are the software counterpart and refer to the fact that (after an exception) control is transferred to the OS  (after a div-by-0, the appropriate trap handler is executed when the exception is  processed by the processor). But many people use them indifferently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traps are initiated by the programmer using the instruction Int in x86. As soon as this instruction is encountered the program control gets transferred to the special handler routine.
Whenever an abnormal condition occurs, exceptions are raised. For example, divide-by-zero condition. The program control is transferred to the exception handlers which are user-defined.

Answer (score 12):

There are interrupts - things that cause the CPU to start executing code from a table (ae.g. n interrupt vector table).

Interrupts can be split into categories depending on what triggered them:

- exceptions - triggered by the CPU itself
- IRQs - triggered by external hardware (e.g. network card)
- software interrupts - triggered explicitly by the code that was running
- IPIs (inter-processor interrupts) - triggered by a different CPU

Exceptions can be further broken down into sub-categories:

- aborts - things that prevent the interrupted code from continuing. These are things that indicate a major problem - e.g. division by zero, hardware failures, etc.
- traps - things that don't prevent the interrupted code from continuing. These can be used for debugging, for virtual memory management, etc.

Mostly; the difference between a trap and an exception is like the difference between a car and a vehicle (a trap is one kind of exception, and a car is one type of vehicle; but there are exceptions that aren't traps and there are vehicles that aren't cars).

> So I've understood both TRAPs and exceptions can be considered software interrupts

This is probably wrong (definitely wrong if you're using Intel's terminology) - a software interrupt is a type of interrupt and not a type of exception. A nice example of this is the difference between an `int3` instruction and an `int 3` instruction on 80x86. The `int3` triggers a breakpoint exception (a trap) while the `int 3` is a software interrupt (not a trap and not an exception) that will probably (depending on the OS) result in a general protection fault (due to violating the "descriptor privilege level" restriction on corresponding interrupt descriptor table's entry).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answers, traps are primarily used for controlled transitions between user mode and kernel mode, typically for system calls, while exceptions are triggered by unexpected events or errors during program execution and are used to handle a wide range of exceptional conditions, including hardware errors and software faults.