# Is it possible to jump to kernel mode if the hardware does not support the trap instruction, but does support interrupts and exceptions

Tags: assembly, x86, operating-system, kernel, cpu-architecture

In order to virtualize the CPU, the hardware helps the software with trap instruction and interrupt. I was wondering if a hardware does support interrupts and exceptions, but does not trap, will this machine still be able to virtualize the CPU by jumping into the kernel mode?

Comment: A system could agree on a specific *exception* corresponded to a system call for example trying to *store* at 0xfeedface; could be interpreted as a syscall op.   It is unlikely that you will find hardware that supports any sort of protection model that lacks a syscall style instruction.

Comment: Your question title seems different than your question body.  Some real-world x86 OSes *did* at one point use the illegal-instruction exception to transfer control to the kernel [as a way to make system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47112309/224132), because on 386 it was faster than `int 0x80`. But your question body is about virtualization.

Comment: The thing with virtualization is that "sensitive" instructions *must* trap.  Being *able* to transfer control to the kernel is not the hard part, it's making sure that always happens for every case where a hypervisor needs to step in.  Also, what definitions are you using for "exception" vs. "trap"?  Those are highly overlapping terms.  If you go by the taxonomy in Brendan's answer on [Difference between TRAP and exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56877451), the only type of exceptions other than traps are aborts, which don't normally allow resuming after.  Is that what you mean?